# VMWare CentOS7 guest - performance declines over time, how to isolate the issue?

Tags: linux, performance, vmware

I use this Dell XPS laptop as a development machine. It has a 6 core i7 (12 logical procs) in it. 32G RAM. I have VMware Workstation 16 Pro, version: 16.2.4 build-20089737. I set up a VM of CentOS-7 with 2 cores, half the available RAM of the host.

At first, the VM worked just fine. Lately though, after I power it on and work for ~10 minutes the performance slows to a crawl; I can barely type on the command line without extra letters showing up...horrible.

I verified I had not run out of space, plenty of that. I tried increasing the cores of the guest to 4 from 2, the problem persists. The only thing I note is that it doesn't seem to matter what I'm doing; meaning, I can power on the guest and let it just sit there and after ~10min if I then start to try something the performance has already dropped off.

I checked dmesg on the host for anything ominous but didn't see anything unusual.

What else is there to check to isolate some causes?

Comment: (1) Generally adding processors to Guest at the expense of Host does not help.  (2) Does your computer have a hard drive and then, so, is the Guest heavily fragmented?  You can shrink a Linux guest which may clean it up.

Comment: oh my! fragmentation...I have been spoiled by modern operating systems taking care of this in the background. I didn't realize VMWare even had this function for the disk. Performing it now...will update when finished

Comment: no dice, ran the defragmentaion function on the disk and the issue is still present.

Comment: Maybe build a new VM, use it and see if the VM is better. I use Virtual Machines a lot